# HTML5 valid itemscope

Tags: html, schema

I am marking up my content with schema.org microformats and am wondering about the itemscope attribute. The example given on http://schema.org/docs/gs.html is

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">
```

Is this valid HTML5? I thought attributes needed values, something like

```
<div itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">
```

Comment: It may be valid now however some older parsers may not treat it as such. For example com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse will throw a SAXParseException


"Attribute name "itemscope" associated with an element type "div" must be followed by the ' = ' character."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a [boolean attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#boolean-attribute), which is valid HTML5.

> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to produce valid XHTML5 (as opposed to HTML5 per se, which does not need to be well-formed XML), then @itemscope will need a value. Per the specs for boolean attributes linked by zzzzBov, to be valid XHTML 5 it will need to be one or the other of empty string or the attribute name, i.e. either `<div itemscope="">` or `<div itemscope="itemscope">`

Answer (score 1):

As zzzBov said, it is valid HTML5.

Same thing with input fields and other types of content:

```
<input type="text" value="Text goes here" disabled>
```

Instead of disabled="disabled", HTML5 reads this as true because `disabled` is present.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - `<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">` is correct.

[Example usage](http://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/#the-basic-syntax)

[Spec on `itemscope`](http://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/#attr-itemscope)